# How does the ui thread handles events when it doesn't have a handler?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

while looking at the android source code and diving into the ui thread. I found that the ui thread doesn't even have a handler. All the ui thread has is a looper. That is kinda strange to me.

If it doesn't have a default handler then how can messages get place into the message queue via sendMessage.

How can dispatch event target be called if the handler is non existent?

Also, how can event like onCreate() or onStart() or onClick() get call if a handler if there is no handler. I thought you need a handler is needed to place work into the messageQueue so that it can be done.

Note: I might be missing something here and maybe it does have a handler but I don't know about it. However, the fact that you have to instantiate a new handler on the onCreate()/ mainUiThread tells me that the handler does not yet exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to figure out how the primary lifecycle events happen is by just throwing an Exception and checking the stack trace.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: For illustration purposes
    at RandomActivity.onCreate(RandomActivity.kt:26)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

In the stacktrace there is `android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage`, the fact it is called by `Handler.dispatchMessage` indicates that it is probably the instance of `Handler` you're referring to.

Comment: Oh wow thanks for that. But now I am no so sure why then I see so many android developer create a handler inside onCreate() for multithreading? Shouldn't they just grab that one?

Comment: That specific handler includes handling for all the lifecycle events so you might accidentally invoke one by re-using a tag. Since each handler instance can contain its own unique `handleMessage` implementation using an internal one would be dangerous. It is also package-private so you cannot get it without reflection.

Comment: But the problem is creating a handler separate from the internal one means that it has to bind to a looper doesn't it? and I believe there can only be one handler per looper due to the fact that dispatchEventTarget refers to the target/the handler to which the thread is currently bound to. So if I create a new one how does this run in parallel with the main handler?

Comment: The handler is stored in the `target` field of the `Message`. When it arrives at the top of the looper queue the Looper uses that field to dispatch the message. So the `Looper` itself is never bound to any specific `Handler`. (`Looper.loop()`: `msg.target.dispatchMessage(msg);`)

Comment: But then that still leave the problem that if you store your instcance of the handler then where does the system handler goes? I am sure the system handler must still be needed for things like onClick() or onStop().

Comment: When talking about Handler the only shared resource is the `Looper` and the queue it contains. Any handler created sets itself as the target of the message and adds it to the underlying queue. The Looper will then at some point in the future get to that message and send it back to the Handler for processing. There is no "system handler", just a specific handler within the `Activity` that can handle the lifecycle events. Since it is package-protected any class in "android.app" can directly access it.

Comment: Now that doesn't make sense because you create handler by saying Handler handler = new Handler(). This handler is bound to the current thread which is the main thread or theUiThread. Now according to what you posted above  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477). This can be indicative of a handler that already exist underneath. So if there is a handler underneath and you instantiate a new handler instance doesn't this mean you essentially have two handlers? So which one of these becomes the target?

Comment: I recommend checking out the description of `Handler` in the JavaDoc. It should clear up the behavior of these objects: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: Ok I have taken a look at the documentation but it is still not obvious what is done. The only thing I can think of is that when you post a message using handler.sendMessage(). The message stores a reference to whatever handler that calls it and then call that handler handMessage(). That is the only way I think it might be possible for the main system handler and my handler to exist at the same time and bound to the same thread. Am I right in this assumption?

Comment: Yes. That is essentially what the `msg.target.dispatchMessage(msg);` line in `Looper.loop()` does.